# Load custom written functions in jQuery after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadURL(url){
        $('#ajax').load(url, function(){
            history.pushState('', 'My Website', baseurl + url);
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click', 'a[rel!=external]', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        loadURL($(this).attr('href'));

    });
});
```

Hello again stackoverflow!

I have some content that I load via AJAX. Now I want to load `link.html`, wich contains this piece of code:

```
<script>
    loadURL('code.txt');
</script>
```

so that after it loaded `link.html`, it directly loads `code.txt`.

Sadly, calling a function that has been created inside `$(document).ready()` doesn't seem to be working as it is undefined for some reason. So I tried

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        loadURL('code.txt');
    });
</script>
```

but this didn't seem to work either.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because since the function `loadURL` is declared within another one, the declared function is private to the container function.

The solution is to declare it as a global function as you want to call the function from other contexts as well. It does not create the problems associated with dom ready state as the function is invoked within a dom ready callback.

```
function loadURL(url){
    $('#ajax').load(url, function(){
        history.pushState('', 'My Website', baseurl + url);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a[rel!=external]', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        loadURL($(this).attr('href'));

    });
});
```